# Angularjs unable to call factory method from javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing angularjs application. I have one javascript function to fill dropdown. I am making http call to get data from api. I have factory to return data. Below is code.

```
function fillperiod(fillperiodService) {
  fillperiodService.getData().then(function(res) {
    $scope.cal = response.data.data.Period;
  });
}
myapp.factory('fillperiodService', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 'cfg', '$q', function($http, $cookieStore, cfg, $q) {
  var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
  var urlapi = baseurl + "api/Vehicle/GetEMIPeriod";
  return {
    getData: function() {
      var q = $q.defer();
      $http.get(urlapi).then(function(response) {
        q.resolve(response);
      }, function(error) {
        q.reject();
      })
      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}]);
```

Above code throws error:

> Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined.

I have declared method getData. I am not sure what i am missing in the above code. May i get some help to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This won't fix your problem but there is no need to use `$q` in your factory, just return `$http.get()` as that is already a promise.

Comment: you need to call `fillperiod` in angular context from where you will pass `fillperiodService` to it, or it need to be a controller/service where `fillperiodService` is injected

Comment: how you are invoking `fillperiod ` and from where?

Comment: Thank you. I am invoking fillperiod inside some $http call.

Comment: there you need to inject `fillperiodService` and have to pass that instance to `fillperiod `

Comment: I understood. How can i inject fillperiodService and pass that instance to fillperiod?  Any example? I have    $scope.SaveSimahVerification = function () {  fillperiod} something like this! How can i inject my factory here?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole the same way you are injecting `$http` to your service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the factory is not injected into your controller. Hence, Inside your function, fillperiodService is undefined. Inject the factory into the controller from which you want to call one of its methods. then it will work.

```
EDIT : 
myapp.controller('fillPeriod', ['fillperiodService', function(fillperiodService){
    //here you can call your fillpersiodService.methodName
}])
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to inject factory inside button click?

Comment: No you would have to inject it in the controller when initialising itself. Please check my edited answer in 10 seconds

Comment: I understood. How can i inject fillperiodService and pass that instance to fillperiod?  Any example? I have    $scope.SaveSimahVerification = function () {  fillperiod} something like this! How can i inject my factory here?

Comment: glad to help :-)

Comment: Thank you. I have one think to ask. I am making lot of api calls! Is it good practice to use $q in each http request?

Comment: $http as such returns a promise, so you can just return $http.get(); instead of using $q and returning q.promise

Answer (score 1):

The injection mechanisms within AngularJS only work for creating things that AngularJS understands (controllers, services, filters, ...).  From the looks of it, you have just a stand alone function, which isn't injected by AngularJS.

I would expect a solution that looks closer to the following would work:

```
myapp.controller('FillPeriodController', ['$scope', 'fillperiodService', 
  function($scope, fillperiodService) {
    $scope.fillperiod = fillperiod;

    function fillperiod() {
      fillperiodService.getData().then(function(res) {
        $scope.cal = response.data.data.Period;
      });
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question we need to know the context from where you are invoking this function. In that context you should check if this factory is injected.

Comment: For your example something like that:
$scope.SaveSimahVerification = ['fillperiodService', function (fillperiodService) { fillperiod}]